# How's a (spring) state machine any better than if/else on the state field?

Tags: spring, state-machine

Assuming I'm modeling a Multipart Upload of CSVs, which will be transformed when completed and send to another microservice.
My MultipartUpload states are `NEW, UPLOAD_IN_PROGRESS, UPLOAD_FINISHED, UPLOAD_FAILED, SEND_IN_PROGRESS, SEND_FAILED, SEND_SUCCESS, DONE`

Now I've the endpoints `/startUpload`, `/uploadPart`, `/finishUpload`.

In my `/finishUpload` endpoint, I'll have to call a service which executes the following

```
// uploadService.finish();
var upload = getMultipartUploadFromDB(uploadUUID);
var stateMachine = getStateMachineFromDBState(upload.getState());
if (stateMachine.getState() != State.UPLOAD_IN_PROGRESS) {
  throw new HumanReadableExceptionExplainingWhyTransitionNotPossible();
}
if (upload.getParts() != upload.expectedParts()) {
  throw new HumanReadableExceptionExplainingPartsMissing();
}
stateMachine.sendEvent(Event.END_UPLOAD);
stateMachine.sendEvent(Event.START_SEND):
boolean success = upload.sendChunks();
if (success) {
   stateMachine.sendEvent(Event.SEND_SUCESS):
} else {
   stateMachine.sendEvent(Event.SEND_FAILED):
}
```

Is that even the correct approach? Or should the events chain each other in it's actions? The only advantage I see here is that an exception would be thrown upon reaching an illegal transition. Though for nice error handling I've to check the state anyway to inform the user why that transition wasn't possible.

Should the `START_SEND` event wrap the upload.sendChunk logic in it's handler? What if an user interaction is needed between states? Like `UPLOAD_IN_PROGRESS` cannot transition into `UPLOAD_FINISHED` until the user calls the `/finishUpload` endpoint. So I couldn't chain it together.

Any pointers where my thoughts are wrong? The current implementation is the same as just using the status field in the DB directly.

Comment: I quite fail to see what the real advantage of the state machine here is. You check your state manually anyway and otherwise the whole things is quite linear. Each of the three endpoints probably has some preconditions that need to be checked, so what exactly is the state machine giving you, expect for a complicated way to encapsulate an enum value?

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz That's exactly what I'm trying to find out. Can I somehow take some advantages from the state machine I'm not seeing here? All examples I find are similar (e.g. order flow). I mean every endpoint has to check the state anyway also in these scenarios. I fail to see any reason to use this pattern in any case